# How to show multiple input fields using onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on("change","#noofpack",function(){
    count = $(this).val();
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
        $("#packageDiv").html('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_price[]" placeholder="Unit Price" required="">');
    }
});
```

I want to show multiple input fields onchange `noofpack` if `count` is `3` then it must show three input fields but what happen here when I change `noofpack` then it show only `1` input fields. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("change","#noofpack",function(){
  count = $(this).val();
  $("#packageDiv").html(""); // First empty the packageDiv
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    // Append more instead oh HTML
    $("#packageDiv").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_price[]" placeholder="Unit Price" required="">');
  }
});
```